# Spring Pageable sorting on multiple columns + AWS API Gateway

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I encountered the issue when using Spring's Pageable and AWS API Gateway together. Spring's url for sorting multiple columns is like this:

```
/items?sort=name,asc&sort=id,asc
```

By going through AWS API Gateway, it becomes like this:

```
/items?sort=id,asc
```

I tried the following:

```
/items?sort=name,asc,id,asc
```

But it is throwing 500 error with message `"No property asc found for type Item!"`

I understand that it should be an issue with AWS API Gateway, but it seems that AWS has ignored it since 2015 according to this [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=811296).

Kindly let me know if you have any alternatives or workarounds, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Oliver Gierke [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1153), the workaround can be

```
/items?sort=name,id,asc
```

so all fields are sorted in the same direction (asc or desc).

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
/items?sort=name,id
```

asc not needed, as default sort direction is asc.

Comment: That's right. I explicitly state asc to hint the reader that desc could also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use multiple `sort` parameters e.g.

```
/items?sort=name,asc&sort=id,asc
```

This is useful, especially if there is a combination of ascending and descending orders e.g.

```
/items?sort=name,asc&sort=id,desc
```

... and Spring should return something like: -

```
{

    ...

    "sort": [
        {
            "direction": "ASC",
            "property": "name",
            "ignoreCase": false,
            "nullHandling": "NATIVE",
            "ascending": true,
            "descending": false
        },
        {
            "direction": "DESC",
            "property": "id",
            "ignoreCase": false,
            "nullHandling": "NATIVE",
            "ascending": false,
            "descending": true
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: AWS API Gateway ignores multiple sort parameters, that's why I was asking about it...